# Why is -1001 not a valid Java integer literal?

Tags: java, integer, literals

In Java, `-1001` is not considered a valid integer literal. Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be bull droppings.

Comment: Actually, if I may step in, the OP has hit upon a common misconception. Upvoted.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as a negative decimal literal in Java; see [JLS§3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

-1001 is an *compile time evaluable constant expression* consisting of a unary negation of the *literal* 1001.

(The same applies to C and C++).

Comment: But interestingly, [not JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals).

Comment: To be exact: there *are* negative literals - they just are not written using a `-` and there are no negative *decimal* literals. To quote the JLS: "The most negative hexadecimal [...] literals of type int - each of
which represents the decimal value -2147483648 (-231) - are respectively: • 0x8000_0000 [...]"

Answer (score 1):

The number -1001 is valid Integer literal in java 7 and above.

Comment: I've found out that -1001 actually is a valid integer literal in Java 7 and above... sorry if I misled someone